# How to provide regular expression for matching $$

Tags: java, regex

I am having `String str = "$$\\frac{6}{8}$$";` I want to match for strings using starting with '$$' and ending with '$$'

How to write the regular expression for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the regex:

```
^\$\$.*\$\$$
```

which in Java will be:

```
^\\$\\$.*\\$\\$$
```

A `$` is a regex metacharacter used as end anchor. To mean a literal `$` you need to escape it with a backslash `\`.

In Java `\` is the escape character in a String and also in the regular expression. So to make a `\` reach the regex engine you need to have `\\` in the String.

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/PVlMy)

Comment: It works, except for that it matches everything from the very first $$ to the very last one. Additionally, I don't see the reason for the anchors. Something like `\$\$.*?\$\$` could be better.

Comment: @maaartinus: I guess you did not read the question completely. I want to match for strings using **starting** with '$$' and **ending** with '$$'

Comment: When we define that "match" means what `Matcher.matches()` does, then you need no anchors. When we define it differently....

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex string:

```
"^$$.*$$$"
```

The `^` anchors the expression to the start of the string being matched, and the last `$` anchors it to the end.  All other `$` characters are taken literally.

Comment: Sane regex parsers should not treat as special any `$` *except* for one appearing at the very end of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You may want something like this:

```
final String str = "$$\\frac{6}{8}$$";
final String latex = "A display math formula " + str + " and once again " + str + " and another one " + "$$42.$$";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\$([^$]|\\$[^$])+\\$\\$");
final Matcher m = pattern.matcher(latex);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```